# Weird errors that appear on first rebuild then disappear on the second rebuild

Tags: c#

I seem to be getting some weird errors while rebuilding the project.

I have a project in witch I have stored all my DomainService. If I right click on the solution and select clean solution then rebuild the project I get a bunch of this errors:

> Error 104
>   The type or namespace name 'Practices' does not exist in the namespace
>   'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
>   D:\Projects\Backend\WebApi\DomainServices\LocalizationService.cs

I get errors for each file where I have imported this namespace:

```
using Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation;
```

Now I have already added a reference to the assembly.

The weirdest thing is that if I rebuild again everything works and no errors are displayed.

Does anyone have any ideea what's going on?

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: Maybe related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3992072/where-does-microsoft-practices-servicelocation-come-from

Comment: *could be* some target framework versions mess in your solution, if you have multiple projects which target different framework versions

Comment: Yeah, when you clean your program it wipes everything, references the whole lot, so that when you rebuild you are building the newest references in your code. Hence you get a reference error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Possibly you have wrong build order, visual studio tries to do this in good way, but sometimes it fails

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/34fcc251-b6fe-4878-8274-fa094ae34151/how-do-i-set-the-build-order-of-projects-in-visual-studio-solution